# if the action of a crossed product $C^{\ast}$-algebra is trivial, then is it a tensor product algebra?

Tags: operator-theory, dynamical-systems, operator-algebras

I am working on a problem on page 120 of the book C*-algebras and Finite-dimensional Approximations. The problem asks me to prove that if the action from the discrete group $\Gamma$ to the algebra $A$ i.e. $\tau\ \colon \Gamma\ \to Aut(A)$ is trivial, then $A\rtimes_{\tau,r}C^{\ast}_r(\Gamma)\cong A\otimes C^{\ast}_r(\Gamma)$. I can prove this by using the Fell's absorption principle. My problem is the full crossed version, say: if the action is trivial, whether  $A\rtimes_{\tau}C^{\ast}(\Gamma)\cong A\otimes C^{\ast}(\Gamma)$? I guess so. But I do not know how to prove that.

Thanks for all help!

Comment: This is wrong! Never mind! In fact $A \rtimes_{\tau}C^{\ast}(\Gamma)$ will be isomorphic to the "max" version of tensor product.

Comment: Can you give an explanation for the argument in the comment?
I've tried to apply universality of max and universality of the full crossed product, but I am not sure how to define the maps

Comment: @ShirlyGeffen You are right. Just apply the universality of max and the full  crossed product. the map is $\sum a_s \cdot s \rightarrow \sum a_s \otimes s$.